# PHP error after theme update

Tags: php

I just updated my theme and I'm having errors on the homepage, the elements of the visual composer do not appear, and I get a php error.

> Undefined index: focus in /inc/admin/option-tree/ot-functions.php:57

```
echo $start." a:focus { color: " . $array['focus'] ."; }\n";  
        }
    }
}
```

I do not know much about php, so I do not know how to solve. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: That warning usually means you should check if the `focus` item exists in the `$array` array. So you could put the `echo` in an `if` block - `if ( ! empty( $array['focus'] ) ) { echo ...; }`

Answer (score 0):

This type of error generally occurs when the index is not set in the array. You can use the function isset in if like if( isset ( $array['focus'] ) && !empty( $array['focus'] ) ){ }. This code will first check either the index focus exists in the $array or not. If the index exists then it will check either it is empty or not. If it fulfills both conditions then it will enter in the body of the if and you will not see the undefined index error.